# Distribution of the outer product of two Gaussian vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, outer-product

Assume that $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbf{I}_n)$ and $\mathbf{y}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbf{I}_p)$ are two independent standard Gaussian vectors.

What is the distribution of their [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) $$\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^T=(x_iy_j)_{i\leq n, j\leq p},$$
which is a $n\times p$ matrix?

In the simple case where $p=n=1$, we end up we the [normal-product distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html), but in higher dimensions, things appear to get trickier and I don't know much about matrix variate distributions.

Comment: I would add that in the case in which $p=n\neq 1$ then the outer product would be a Wishart distribution. For the rectangular case, I don't know.

Comment: Doesn't $\mathbf{x}$ needs to be equal to $\mathbf{y}$ if we want $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^T$ to be Wishart ? In the simplest $n=p=1$ case, it is clear that $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^T$ does not follow a 1-dimensional Wishart (which is simply a chi-squared distribution).

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong. Looks like that if you're able to come up with a reasonable derivation is something worth publishing :)

Answer (score 2):

If $n=p$, then since $2 xy^\top + 2 yx^\top = (x+y)(x+y)^\top - (x-y)(x-y)^\top$ (polarization identity), and $x+y$ is decorrelated (and thus independent) from $x-y$, at least you can say that the symmetrization of $x y^\top$ (that is $xy^\top + yx^\top$) is distributed as the difference of two independent Wishard distribution (which is not a Wishard distribution).